# XmlReader.Create get "the process cannot access the file because it it being used by another process" error

Tags: c#, file-io, xmlreader, filesystemwatcher

I have the following code inside the FileSystemWatcher file created event. So whenever a file is created, it will run the code below:

```
    private static void FileWatch_RequestAdded(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
          try
          {
              RequestFile request = GetRequest(e.FullPath);

              EventHandler<MESRequestEventArgs> requestReceived = Instance.RequestReceived;
              if (requestReceived != null)
                 requestReceived(Instance, new MESRequestEventArgs(e.Name, request));               
          }
          catch (Exception error)
          {
               MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
          }
    }

private static object locker = new object();

public static RequestFile GetRequest(string filepath)
{
     string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
     RequestFile file = new RequestFile(filename);        

     XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
     settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;

     lock (locker)
     {
         using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filepath, settings))
         {
             XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RequestFile));
             file = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as RequestFile;                    
         }
    }

     file.Name = filename;           
     return file;
}
```

The problem is when multiple files created at the same time, sometimes it will threw exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it it being used by another process error.

Any solutions?

Comment: show how/where you create instance of "locker"

Comment: Why don't you check if the file is in use before you try to read it

Comment: if that is the case, I would think it has to do with when and how you call this method, not the method itself. It sounds like a multithreading issue.

Comment: What part of the exception do you not understand? The file is already open. The next question is: who has it open, and why didn't your lock prevent that?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I copied and paste 4 different files with diff file name into the folder where the filewatcher is watching, then one of the file will get this exception.

Comment: "One of those files" is still open. Here, try this: create four or more new text files in a different folder. Just use Notepad. Then copy and paste all four into the folder you're watching. Since you will have created the files new, you will _know_ that nobody else is using these files. See if you get the error. If you still get the error, and if nobody _else_ is using the files, then the only code that could be using the files is your own code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am very sure there is nobody else is using these files

Comment: Then it is certainly your own program. I have had this happen.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Do you see any problem or have any solution on my code?

Comment: Yes. I see the solution, but I won't tell you, since I have never liked you since the day we met.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your lock is not exclusive and only getting set in class scope. If you are trying to acquire an exclusive lock, then your `locker` instance must be static or singleton and shared among all calls of file watch handler. Instantiating `locker` within instance class won't be shared a resource, as such lock may not be exclusive among multiple threads.

Something like the following should allow you to have static instance that can be shared across your threads for exclusive locks.

```
static object _locker = new object();
```

Comment: the `locker` is already a static instance define outside the function